# Conflicting types for "free"

Tags: c, free

I'm getting the error

> Conflicting types for 'free'

on the call to `free()` function below.

```
int main ( )
{
    char fx [] = "x^2+5*x-1";
    node * fxNode = buildTree(fx, sizeof(fx)/sizeof(char));
    printf(deriveFromTree(fxNode)); // Should print "2*x+5"
    free(fxNode);
    return 0;
}
```

Can't figure out why. Not sure if this matter, but what's above it is

```
#include <stdio.h>

char opstack [5] = {'+','-','*','^', '\0'};

unsigned short int lowerOpPrecedence ( char, char, char * );

int stringToUnsignedInt ( char *, unsigned int * );
int stringToDouble ( char * , double * );
unsigned short int stringCompare ( char * , char * );
void stringCopy ( char * , char * );

typedef struct treeNode
{
    char * fx;
    char * op;
    struct treeNode * gx;
    struct treeNode * hx;
} node;


unsigned short int getNodeState ( node * );
node * buildTree ( char *, int );
char * basicDerivative ( char * );
char * derivateFromTree ( node * );
```

and what's below it is a bunch of function implementations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add `#include <stdlib.h>` to provide the prototype for `free()`.

Also, the recommended signature for `main()` is `int main (void)`.

Comment: Dang it. I'm trying to write a program from scratch -- no libraries besides `<stdio.h>`. Is there a way for me to implement a `free` function from scratch?

Comment: @FiredfromMicrosoft `<stdio.h>` is not a library, it's a header file. If you don't want to include the header file, you can add the forward declaration in your source code itself.

Comment: Writing `free` from scratch sounds like reinventing the wheel. Why would you want to do it?

Comment: @FiredfromMicrosoft Using `free()` implies that you're probably also using `malloc()` or `calloc()`, and both are also defined in `<stdlib.h>`. Failure to include this header file can cause disastrous bugs.

Comment: if your code is going to use 'free()' then it also needs access to the 'malloc()' family of functions.   Trying to write a program without using the relevant libraries is, (IMO) a futile exercise.  One programming goal is to re-use the efforts of those that came before, rather than 're-inventing the wheel'.  I.E. libraries are your friends.

Comment: You can implement malloc and free, but it is an advanced exercise.  Try googling `How to implement malloc and free`.  In general though `<stdlib.h>` is such a basic part of C that you should take it as part of the language.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your `malloc` and `free` above some operating system memory [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) primitives (modifying the [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) of your [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29)), like (on Linux) [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and `munmap`. Details are operating system specific.

BTW, if your goal is to write a program using only `<stdio.h>` most implementations of it are internally using `malloc`, since the buffer inside every `FILE` is generally some dynamically allocated byte zone (so concretely, it is generally allocated thru `malloc`). In other words, the implementation of `fopen` very probably uses `malloc`; see also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/279788/40065). Hence if you accept to include `<stdio.h>` you should accept to include `<stdlib.h>`...

Notice that several [standard C libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (a.k.a. `libc`) are [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software); you could study -and improve- the source code of GNU [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or of [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30005411/841108) to a related question.

Answer (score 0):

if your linker command file contains a specific definition of the heap, including a label at the start address and a length label,

then you could write your own version of malloc, free, realloc, calloc, etc.

BTW: the code is calling 'free()'  How was that memory allocation made that 'free()' will be returning to the heap?